# Loops showing infront of ears

Tags: topology, retopology

i am currently trying to retopologize this face shown in the images below. However, the planes around the ear are showing in front of the side of the head. Is there any way to solve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must have activated this option on your low poly version of the head:
[image]

Uncheck it and it should be alright